# What tools exist to automatically recover from very large load averages on linux?

Tags: linux, load-average

For a number of different reasons in the last year or two, I have had issues with servers that run processes which tend to cause very heavy load averages.

In these cases, I can often ping the server, but it becomes very unresponsive to any other connections, and I often have to power cycle the machine.

One reason for causing this huge load include a poorly configured Apache process on a virtual server that allowed too many concurrent connections for the hardware allocated to it, and I seem to have ran some programs on another server tonight that appears to have done something similar.

What I am curious about is linux has tools that detect a very large load average and interrupt those processes in some way, allowing the machine to recover from this?

My apologies if I have not worded this well, I appreciate it is pretty open-ended.

Comment: There couldn't possibly exist a tool to automatically recover from a high load average. A high load average is not itself a problem but it may be a symptom of an underlying problem. There is no such thing as automatically recovering from a symptom without first fixing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you've answered your own question.

> One reason for causing this huge load
>   include a poorly configured Apache
>   process on a virtual server...

If you have a poorly configured Apache server, fix that configuration.  You've already done the investigation, so now you should implement the proper fix.  A script to interrupt/restart/kill processes that runaway is only a workaround.

All that being said - I don't know of any tools that would do what you're looking for.  But I don't think you need a tool, you need a proper configuration for the system you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

baumgart is correct, that you should solve the problem. However as a work around, you can have [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) execute scripts if the load average goes too high. It's something of a hack though, so it's far from perfect. You could also write something to do this relatively trivially.